# Remove quotes from cell in MS Excel and save as a docx file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a DOCX (MS Word file) with a macro that I later grab with a template builder. I want to automate this as much as possible.

The following article addresses the issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910288/leave-out-quotes-when-copying-from-cell?newreg=312c7ace7e0b439291cfcde3533cb224

And this post gives me a great solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55399893/19730828

Here it is in the Macro I created:

Sub SimpleVBAWriteToFileWithoutQuotes()
Open "c:\TEMP\Excel\out.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3)
Close #1
End Sub

But I need to save the output as a docx (word) file instead of txt. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: open the txt file in word and resave as docx.

Comment: I can do that from Excel, but it copies a quote at the beginning and end. I know I can simply remove it, but I want to automate the creation of the word file as I am referencing it from a template builder. If I can use a macro to create the DOCX file, then the template builder can grab it.

Comment: Please adjust your question to include the specific solution/code you created and where you hit a wall (I understand its adapted from the links you referenced).  I don't understand what 'that' means in your comment "I can do 'that' from Excel,"  (i.e. you can create a docx file in Excel but with a quote around the content?  Something else?)

Comment: I have adjusted the question to include the macro.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions for me.

Comment: Out of the city with intermittent internet access.  Might be a delay, but will look at it.